# express -s not working

Tags: node.js, express

Has support for sessions been removed from express or is there a new command? I cant seem to find an answer anywhere. This is the result of me trying to use it.

```
Last login: Fri Jun 20 14:42:17 on ttys001
new-host-2:~ Brennan$ cd Desktop/
new-host-2:Desktop Brennan$ mkdir test6
new-host-2:Desktop Brennan$ cd test6
new-host-2:test6 Brennan$ express -s

  error: unknown option `-s'

new-host-2:test6 Brennan$
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, you're correct.  Many middlewares had been removed from express 4 including session.  Therefore, -s is no longer part of the express command.  Here are some of the middlewares removed:

```
basicAuth()
bodyParser()
compress()
cookieParser()
cookieSession()
csrf()
directory()
```

Here is an example how to add session support to express 4 with cookie-session middeware:

```
var express = require('express');
var session = require('cookie-session');

var app = express();

app.use(session({
  keys: ['key1', 'key2'],
  secureProxy: true // if you do SSL outside of node
}));
```

Comment: This should be in the javascript file where you setup express and node server.